# Type not found: type .. when type is in src_managed folder

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide

After *sbt eclipse*, when I import a project to my eclipse workspace, I get the error that

> type not found:X

When I search for that type X, I find it in the src_managed folder of the same project.

- I am using Scala IDE 4.0.0 RC2
- I have set my Scala Installation to my project(2.10.4)
- It does not have any projects that it depends on
- I can compile it in sbt i.e. sbt.{project myProject,compile}. NOTE: When I do this, and I come back and refresh the project in Eclipse, suddenly all errors "seem" to have gone away, but if I click on the particular file, the error still exists. It just does not show up in the Package Explorer and Problems View.

Answer (score 0):

Say, the generated code is in target/scala-2_10/src_managed/main/compiled_avro/org/...

then 
I had to add the source folder for the generated code in  Java Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder -> Select the folder compiled_avro.