# Object not found when is in src_managed folder

Tags: scala, sbt

This is (I think) a different question from [Type not found: type .. when type is in src_managed folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192089/type-not-found-type-when-type-is-in-src-managed-folder).

I am building from sbt, 1.1.1, I have set up a code generation task in sbt that is runnign as expected and creaing a number of files with the same structure.

```
package com.a3.traffic
package object Vendor
```

And they are imported in other files as:

```
import com.a3.traffic.Vendor._
```

The files are generated under src_managed. I have tried two different setups

```
src_managed / main / Vendor

src_managed / main / scala / com / a3 / traffic / Vendor
```

In both cases I get the following error:

```
[error] /Users/luis/IdeaProjects/SparkTrafficAllocation/core/src/main/scala/com/a3/traffic/Params.scala:5:28: object Vendor is not a member of package com.a3.traffic
[error] import com.a3.traffic.Vendor._
```

I can fix that by moving the generatd code to src / main / scala / com / a3 / traffic  / Vendor (that is with the rest of my code) but then I get this.

```
[error] /Users/luis/IdeaProjects/SparkTrafficAllocation/core/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/scala/com/a3/traffic /Vendor/Vendor.scala:3:16: package is already defined as package object Vendor
[error] package object Vendor {
```

I find this quite puzzling. The objects defined in src_managed can not be seen from my code, but it can see what is in the package.How can I make the objects in src_managed available to the rest of the package?

EDIT
I created a minimal project to show this https://github.com/sisamon/MinimalApp

EDIT 2
I am using a name / package.scala / package.scala => object name as the original name.scala case class / case object was not working.

Comment: Can you share a sample repo which we can reproduce the problem?, This is quite weird. I had done it a couple of times and it always works. By any chance had you modify something in **SBT** related to the compile classpath - by default the _src_managed_ folder is always present for compilation, and as long as the objects defined there are in a package and are public you may be able to use them. As you can see in this simple demo I made, I use all objects created in the generated file in my `Main.scala` file.

Comment: Also, the las error message is quite weird, it says that the the `package object Vendor` is already defined. When you did the experiment of moving the generated file to the rest of the code, did you disable the code generation and deleted the old one? - that way you can check if given that, it will work as expected.

Comment: No, i did not (for this experiment) For "production"i will do as such but I was really curious about why it was not finding the objects.It is not really so weird as the object Vendor is in both the managed and unmanaged source directories. I will try to build a smaller project that still shows the problem. The one I am using is fairly complex. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, when you have it edit the question with the link, I will take a look as soon as I can. Also I just noticed I forgot to add the link to the [demo](https://github.com/BalmungSan/fastpath-demo) I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Your `Vendor` class should actually be named `SparkTrafficAllocation/core/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/scala/com/a3/traffic/package.scala`. It should contain `package com.a3.traffic` \n `package object Vendor { ... }`

Comment: ... and package objects (since they are actual packages) usually start with lower case letters

Comment: @aki, fixed the file name and lowercase convention but it made no difference

Comment: @LuisSisamon sorry for late response, I was hoping you to tag me after the edit. The link is broken - did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sorry, I forgot to tag and to make repo public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in [here](https://github.com/sisamon/MinimalApp/blob/master/project/ADTGenerator.scala#L22).

```
def generator (x: Country) = {
  generateADT("Vendor", x.vendor)
  generateADT("InstallationType", x.installationType)
}
```

Remember that your task **MUST** returns a `Seq` with the **ALL** `Files` that were *generated*!.

And, your `generateADT` each return a `Seq` of one `File`, and as such, you are returning only the `Seq` of the last call *(which in this case is `InstallationType`)*, that is why your `Vendor` is not found!

You can check that by commenting the second line, which will make the first line the return, in that case the `Vendor` will be found!

There a couple of ways to fix this, the most simple & *elegant* *(IMHO)* would be this:

```
def generator (x: Country): List[File] =
  List(
    ("Vendor", x.vendor),
    ("InstallationType", x.installationType)
  ).map((generateADT _).tupled)

def generateADT (base: String, d: Descriptor): File = {
  // ...
  // The path really does not matter, as long as it is inside the src_managed folder.
  val adtFile = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / s"${base}.scala"
  IO.writeLines(adtFile, code)
  adtFile
}
```

PS: As an advice, you should explicitly put the return type of all functions/methods. Not only it will help the type inference of other things, also it will avoid a couple of compile errors and will increase the readability of your code.

Comment: Yes I should have typed the function with the return value. This effectively fixes the problem, but I still do not get why i had the second problem, seeing them after i copied them into my main code. There is clearly something I do not get about the scope rules.

Comment: @LuisSisamon I think _(and this is only pure speculation)_, that **SBT** still compiles everything inside the `src_managed` folder before compiling the normal source code. And for the source code it only puts in scope the files which it knows it have to use - or it is only black magic, who knows is **SBT**.